# Blazor Server website with Azure Identification

Tags: blazor-server-side, azure-ad-msal

I'm spinning around and around trying to find a comprehensive description on how to upgrade a Blazor server website without authentication to use the latest MSAL authentication and not ADAL which is going to be dropped in 2022.
The issue I had are that there are bit and pieces here and there and finally I got it to compile and start up, but when the website gives me a choice of the login since I have multiple ad connections, it repeats that choice after I select one. It never gets to complete the handshake in some form.
Here is what I have:

Startup.cs in ConfigurationService:

```
    services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAd");

    services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                         .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                         .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

Appsettings is:

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "zzzzzzzzz.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "ClientId": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
},
```

LaunchSettings:

```
"ITraxBlazer": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },
```

"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
}

Packages:

```
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Blazored.Toast" Version="3.1.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.5.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="1.5.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="5.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Telerik.Documents.Spreadsheet" Version="2021.1.118" />
        <PackageReference Include="Telerik.UI.for.Blazor" Version="2.21.0" />
      </ItemGroup>
```

Thanks a bunch for any help!

Comment: One more clarification, once I start the app, it asks me for which account to chose and after my choice and entering the password, it keeps on asking me which account to chose but shows the selected account as "Signed In".

Comment: I think I have it narrowed down to the following:
1. If I run it without Authentication, the website's location is: https://localhost:44398/
2. If I enable Authentication and remove the "Redirect URIs" in Azure, I get an error AADSTS500113 (no reply address is registered for the application).
3. If I register https://localhost:44398/, then I get AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application
4. If I register localhost:44398/signin-oidc, I get a request to choose my Azure login over and over.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I didn't have the two indented lines here in StartUp.cs

```
app.UseRounting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints();
```